# Python PulP optimization with list of variables and binary variable

Tags: python, optimization, binary, constraints, pulp

I'm attempting to a simple optimization using 4 variables that have lists of data.  All I want to do is multiple the first 3 variables and divide the result by the 4rth variable.  Then I want the binary variable to be a 1 or 0, which I multiply by the result to determine if the "row" is included or excluded from the summed result.  My only constraint is variable 4, which can't exceed a number when summed from the 1 or 0.

```
import pulp as pl

x1 = [.1, .8, .2, .15, .6]
x2 = [5000, 8000, 10000, 4500, 2200]
x3 = [.1, .1, .15, .08, .1]
x4 = [5, 3, 8, 10, 2]
x5 = pl.LpVariable('x5', cat=pl.LpBinary)


res = [(x1[i] * x2[i] * x3[i]) / x4[i] for i in range(5)]

test = pl.LpProblem('test_this', pl.LpMaximize)

test += pl.lpSum([res[i] for i in range(len(res))] * x5)

test += pl.lpSum([x4[i] for i in range(5)] * x5) <= 20

test.solve()

print(x5.value())
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.  I get a type error.  I don't think my logic is correct and was hoping someone could educate me on how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: I figured it out - i had to make a list of the decision variables....duh.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - i had to make a list of the decision variables....duh.